# Nesting in BASH script with Variables

Tags: bash, variables, escaping

I have a task to find files, not changed for 5 minutes, with possible 1 sub folders, in a for loop, and auto ftp this to a remote location.
To do this the find command is working fine for me.
But I need to strip off the base folder and file name to find the possible sub folder and use that in a ncftpput command.

I started with this:

```
HOST=1.2.3.4
USER=foo
PASS=bar
LDIR="/storage/external/ftp/foo/bar"

for FOUND in `find ${LDIR}/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -mmin +1 `; do
    RDIR="$FOUND | cut -d / -f 6"   
    echo "LDIR = $LDIR"
    echo "RDIR = $RDIR"
    echo "FOUND = $FOUND"
    ncftpput -u $USER -p $PASS -R -DD $HOST /$RDIR/ $FOUND
    echo " "
done
```

But the RDIR="$FOUND | cut -d / -f 5" returns not with the right value. either blank or with syntax error, or with a path + | cut -d / -f 6.
Also tried other ticks,backticks, $() etc.

tried:

```
RDIR= "$FOUND | cut -d / -f 6"
RDIR= '$FOUND | cut -d / -f 6'
RDIR= `$FOUND | cut -d / -f 6`
RDIR= $FOUND | cut -d / -f 6
RDIR= $($FOUND | cut -d / -f 6)
RDIR= "$($FOUND | cut -d / -f 6)"
RDIR= '$($FOUND | cut -d / -f 6)'
RDIR= `$($FOUND | cut -d / -f 6)`
```

than I gave up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a start:

```
RDIR=$(echo "$FOUND" | cut -d / -f 6)
```

Probably (you should check), it should be `-f 7` to know the subfolder.
Moreover, in the find command shouldn't it be `-mmin +5`?

Comment: It really was that easy :)
Thanks a lot mate.